# Not able to make XMLHttpRequest from sandboxed page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am porting a sencha web app ( basically a JS, HTML, CSS webapp) into a chrome app. As sencha framework make extensive use of eval() and new function, I have to sandbox my app. I am able to display front page which asks for authentication.

When I am providing my details and hitting OK to login, I am not able to connect to server.

Server is in Spring. I have checked server logs. Server is not getting any request.

I am getting "Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I have checked response header, Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set when I make request from browser. But it is not set when I make same request from chrome app.

Comment: You might want to read up on CORS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. As the error message says, the null origin is a problem.

Comment: Does the server have a whitelist of origins that are allowed?